# [asp.net]problem with refreshing the updatepanel from server code

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

In my app I have a simple upload with jquery and custom http handler binded to button and an update panel to show the uploaded file name:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFile" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <%= System.DateTime.Now %>
    <input id="File1" type="file" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <br />
            <br />
            <%= System.DateTime.Now %>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#file_upload').fileUpload({
            url: '../UploadHandler.ashx',
            method: 'POST',
            onLoadAll: function (list)
            {
               // __doPostBack('MainContent_UpdatePanel1', '');
            }
        });
    });

    $('#File1').hide();

    $('#MainContent_btnUploadFile').click(function ()
    {
        $('#File1').click();

        return false;
    });
});
```

The handler looks that:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadedfile = context.Request.Files[0];

            string fileName = uploadedfile.FileName;

            IMainFormViewPresenter presenter = Bootstrapper.ServiceLocator.GetService<IMainFormViewPresenter>();
            //do sth..
            presenter.SetFileInfo(fileName);
            presenter.RefreshUpdatePanel();
        }
```

and in the view

```
public void RefreshUpdatePanel()
        {
           // UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
public void SetFileInfo(string fileName)
        {
            Label1.Text = fileName;
        }
```

The problem is that, the UpdatePanel1.Update() in the server code doesn't work. Sometimes I get exception: The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' before Render.

I can't find out what is going on. The update panel refreshed from javascript work ok, but I'm curious why on the server is problem.
Full solution I put here https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/WebApplication1.rar?w=ea9959b6

Answer (score 0):

Since the button is outside of your update panel you will need to add a trigger to your update panel that has the controlID of your button and the event of click so in your update panel add the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <br />
        <br />
        <%= System.DateTime.Now %>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadFile" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This will tell your update panel to treat the button as if it were inside of the update panel and to participate in partial postbacks as if it were inside of the update panel.

HTH.

Comment: What in situation, when the button is on diffrent usercontrol? (not in this example but this is only a little segment cut from my project). I will check the solution with trigger, but in that situation when can I use directly the Update() method? Only in events from controls which are placed in this updatepanel?

Comment: If I understand the request, you would have to register the control that is causing the postback (your user control, or a control inside of your user control) with the updatepanel's trigger collection, an example of how to do this can be found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1124967.aspx

Comment: I have moved button from the above solution to user control and added to the main form to Page_Load event:

        AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger(); 
        trigger.ControlID = ((Button)WebUserControl11.Controls[0]).ClientID; 
        trigger.EventName = "click"; 
    UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger); 

but I have exception:

 A control with ID 'MainContent_WebUserControl11_btnUploadFile' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think it would be ((Button)WebUserControl11.Controls[0]).ClientID (that is mainly used for javascript interaction between controls) It should be just ((Button)WebUserControl11.Controls[0]).ID

Comment: When I change ClientID to ID nothing changes. The same exception occurs.